# Point cPanel new account's domain to server

Tags: php, dns, cpanel, whm, a-records

I had create a cPanel account by following [this api](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/whm/operation/createacct/). After account created, I able to login to the cPanel but this account's domain has SSL issue and the domain was unable to resolved.
Domain Example : example.com
Host Example : h1.hostname.com

I had try to update zone record by following this [api](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/whm/operation/editzonerecord/) and try to add a new zone record by following this [api](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/whm/operation/addzonerecord/).
What should I do to let the domain point to my hosting server? I would like to achieve this without any plugin or software and using code only.